# Spring security authorize rails app using devise

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, tomcat, spring-security, pentaho

I'm trying to figure out how to authorize my rails app into pentaho spring security. I've tried to use the URL parameters user=username&password=password but somehow the application does not listen to it and it just send me to the login page.

Right now im doing a hack on the pentaho server by allowing Anonymous access to the url patterns in the the file `biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml`

> \A/viewaction.*\Z=Admin,Anonymous
>
> \A/content/reporting.*\Z=Anonymous,Authenticated

However by doing this i'm allowing access not just rails but to anyone who access those urls.

What i need is to either to enable the execution of the urls using the user and password parameters in the url or authorize my rails app to have read/execute access to those patterns.

Any help appreciated.